# What does this "max" line mean?

Tags: c, max

I don't understand the following line. *sockfd1* and and *sockfd2* are sockets.

```
max = (sockfd1 < sockfd2 ? sockfd2 : sockfd1);
```

I use  this line for the select :

```
//Initialisation du fd_set    
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(sockfd1, &readfds);
FD_SET(sockfd2, &readfds);
max = (sockfd1 < sockfd2 ? sockfd2 : sockfd1);

//Le select()    
select(max+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Comparing the numeric values of two file descriptors is generally not meaningful... do you have some more context?

Comment: You need to learn C Basic ternary http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html

Comment: I put the context in the post above ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ternary operator `?:` evaluates its first argument, and if it's true, it returns the second, otherwise the third.  So if `sockfd1 < sockfd2`, the result will be `sockfd2`, otherwise `sockfd1` -- in other words, `max` receives the numerically greater socket file descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like all the other answers are explaining the ternary operator.  I'm guessing you're confused because this code is comparing two sockets numerically.

In Linux/Unix, `socket()` is the function to create a socket, but it only returns an integer.  All the other data that the OS needs to send and receive data on the socket, such as its IP address, is stored inside the kernel.  When you call an API like `send()`, you pass this number and the kernel uses it to find all the other relevant information about the socket in its own data structures.

Files, pipes, and other stuff in Unix behave the same way.  These integers are called File Descriptors.

So this code is comparing the numerical values of two file descriptors.  I can't think of why this would be useful except for defining an arbitrary ordering on two sockets.  The numerical value of file descriptors is not meaningful.

Comment: It might be useful if, for instance, the sockets were obtained using [`socketpair(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socketpair) and you're trying to determine which is which, but since the sockets are symmetrical anyway, you really ought to be keeping track of that information yourself.

Comment: That is interesting.  I never heard of `socketpair(2)` before.  But I also think your case qualifies as "defining an arbitrary ordering on two sockets." `:)`

Comment: I put the context in the post above ;)

Comment: @Danvdb: In this case, the code is trying to determine the value to pass to `select()`, which requires that you pass an upper bound on the size of the fd set.

Answer (score 1):

It sets `max` equal to the larger of `sockfd1` and `sockfd2`.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as

```
if (sockfd < sockfd)
  max = sockfd2;
else
  max = sockfd1;
```

The ternary operator `?:`is just a [syntaxic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)

Answer (score 0):

There is used so-called conditional or ternary operator:

```
(sockfd1 < sockfd2 ? sockfd2 : sockfd1);
```

If expression

```
sockfd1 < sockfd2
```

is true then the value of the operator is  sockfd2 otherwise `sockfd1`

So max will be assigned the maximum between two values.

From the C Standard (6.5.15 Conditional operator)

> 4 The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between
>   its evaluation and the evaluation of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated). The second operand is evaluated only if the
>   first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second
>   or third operand (whichever is evaluated), converted to the type
>   described below.110) ∗